User permission issues when connecting to a DSLR camera using the ImageCaptureCore framework
Recently, when I used the ImageCaptureCore framework to connect an iPhone to a SLR camera in MTP and PTP modes, two permissions appeared when obtaining camera connection permissions: 1. Obtain camera permissions, namely CameraUsageDescription permissions; 2. A pop-up window titled "would like to access files on connected cameras and storage" appeared. I would like to ask how the second permission is implemented.
The Code:
let deviceBrowser = ICDeviceBrowser()
        deviceBrowser.delegate = self
        if #available(iOS 15.2, *) {
            deviceBrowser.browsedDeviceTypeMask = ICDeviceTypeMask(rawValue: ICDeviceTypeMask.camera.rawValue | ICDeviceLocationTypeMask.local.rawValue) ?? ICDeviceTypeMask(rawValue: 0)!
        }
        deviceBrowser.requestControlAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Authorization not determined.")
            case .restricted:
                print("Authorization restricted.")
            case .denied:
                print("Authorization denied.")
                self.requestCompletion?(true)
            case .authorized:
                print("Authorization granted.")
                self.requestCompletion?(true)
            default:
                print("Unknown authorization status.")
            }
        } deviceBrowser.requestContentsAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Authorization not determined.")
            case .restricted:
                print("Authorization restricted.")
            case .denied:
                print("Authorization denied.")
                self.requestCompletion?(true)
            case .authorized:
                print("Authorization granted.")
                self.requestCompletion?(true)
            default:
                print("Unknown authorization status.")
            }
        }
        deviceBrowser.start()

